# Adding two Infinite Decimals $x$ and $y$

Tags: real-analysis

I am attempting to develop an algorithm for adding two infinite decimals $x$ and $y$. I am working from left to right, adding the digits of $x$ to those of $y$. Evidently, if the sum of the digits of $x$ and $y$ at a particular index $i$ is less than 10, then we can simply sum the digits together; but if the sum exceeds 10, then a 'carrier' operation has to be performed. I'm presently stuck on showing why, no matter how many carrier operations are performed, any particular digit is modified at most once. How could I go about showing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are adding from left to right and modifying digits comes when you carry into a column.  To modify a digit twice you would need to carry into the column twice, which means that the stuff to the right of that column would have to add to two units in the column, but that is impossible.

If we consider the $10^{-k}$ column, it can only be modified if the sum of the $10^{-(k+1)}$ and rightward columns of the two addends sums to at least $2 \cdot 10^{-k}$, but that part of each addend is less than $10^{-k}$ so the sum cannot be as much as $2 \cdot 10^{-k}$

Comment: Should the algorithm proceed as follows? Get the first index $i \in \mathbb{N}$ at which $a_i + b_i \geq 10$. Modify the previous digit by adding $+1$ to it. If such a digit ≠ 9, then all earlier digits are now fixed; if such a digit $= 9$, then re-iterate the procedure described until either we reach a digit $≠ 9$ or we simply add $+1$ to the integer part of the number. Proceed to the next index $i$ for which $a_i + b_i \geq 10$. Because any digit is only modified once, we need not considered the digits we had modified previously...(*) In general, there may be $\infty$ iterations.

Comment: (*) But, altogether, this feels very scrappy; I think I am having trouble properly stating the algorithm in words & formalising it.

Comment: Take the *state* at any time to be $N$, the digit you haven’t output yet, and $n_9$, the number of nines that go after that digit. A sum $=9$ increments $n_9$. A sum $<9$ outputs $N$ followed by $n_9$ nines, sets $N$ to the new sum and $n_9$ to zero. A sum $>9$ outputs $N+1$ followed by $n_9$ zeroes, sets $N$ to the new sum minus $10$ and $n_9$ to zero.

Comment: You can't have a finite algorithm to add truly infinite decimals.  Just start adding from the left, the tenths place. You get a sum, which is tentative.  Then add the hundredths place.  If there is a carry, update the tenths and output it because it can't change again.  If there is no carry and the hundredths is less than $9$ output the tenths because it can't change.  Otherwise go on to the next place.  Each time you carry or get a digit less than $9$ you output all the places that are now set.